# PHP 6.0 - Roadmap?

Tags: php

[With the recent announcement](http://news.php.net/php.internals/47120) that PHP 6 development has been halted, I'm confused as to what the PHP 5.x and 6.x road map includes.

The current version of PHP is 5.3.2.

There were quite a few significant features to come in PHP 6.0, such as:

- APC include for automatic bytecode caching
- Unicode support
- etc..

Question: What is the new road map of PHP given 6.0 has been canceled? What major features will be available next and in what release?

Comment: Voted to close - these type of "moment in time" questions are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow - especially those which can only be answered with speculation and conjecture.

Comment: It's a good question, but no answer exists yet. The whole thing's a horrible bloody mess. (And you thought Perl 6 was a messy transition...)

Comment: The PHP Development team doesn't even know the answers to these questions yet so surely no one else will either. All I can say is for everybody to remain calm and just enjoy the anonymous functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610763/what-is-the-holdup-on-php-6

Comment: @bobince the fact that there is no answer IS the answer.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because there will be no PHP 6.

Answer (score 14):

Features:

- Unicode support;
- APC opcode cache as standard;
- Removal of several deprecated features (eg magic quotes, register globals, the ereg library and safe mode).

No firm date has been set. Anything you read is purely conjecture.

You may want to read [Future of PHP 6](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/128-Future-of-PHP-6.html). PHP6 has somewhat stalled, particularly on the Unicode issues. Just to set the level of your expectations, [people have been discussing PHP6 since *at least 2006*](http://developers.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=06/03/14/0455221).

Comment: So, will those feature be in v5.4 (if such a version will exist) ... or will they be available in the 5.3 branch?

Comment: @JustinT I don't think even the PHP team knows the answer to those questions.

Comment: None of the changes mentioned in this answer are valid for a "bug fix" release, so at least the 2nd digit in the version number has to change. They won't appear in PHP 5.3. -- johannes (PHP 5.3 Release Master)

Comment: Unicode is quite the beast. Checking for Unicode issues is part of the checklist in every web application I work on these days.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an article I read recently on the matter: [Resetting PHP 6](http://lwn.net/Articles/379909/)

It goes into some detail the cause of the delay.

Answer (score 2):

Horizontal code reuse!

Actually, I'm surprised it's not mentioned yet, it's the biggest feature IMO.
Basically, it's a way to ease code reuse, by adding methods to classes without inheriting from another class. It's similar to multiple inheritance, but avoids the diamond problem.

Comment: Read the article that Grant Palin linked.

Comment: The only diamond problem I know of is that I don't own any. Are there others?

Comment: The diamond problem is referring to multiple inheritance, where you inherit from two classes that themselves inherit from the same base class.

Comment: Traits look really nice. Not so sure I can see the benefits of grafts over traits immediately, but I'm certainly looking forward to playing with it

Answer (score 2):

Unicode branch is on hold for now. Nobody knows what happens with it yet, until there's a good plan how to proceed. The trunk branch - probably to be named 5.4 (or, less probably, 6) - is being actively developed, is to feature significant performance improvements, traits (already in) and some other goodies you can find on http://wiki.php.net/rfc/ or directly from the [SVN NEWS](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/NEWS?view=markup) file. It would probably be released reasonably soon, but no set dates yet.

P.S. "active development" also means "don't rely on anything you see there too much yet unless you are ready for big changes without notice". Consider yourself warned :)

Answer (score 0):

The recent release of PHP 5.3 included most of what was originally desirable about PHP6. At last year's Zendcon there was a presentation titled "State of PHP 6", you can see the slides of this presentation here: http://zmievski.org/files/talks/zendcon-2009/php-code-ideas-people.pdf